# MFC (CAtlRegExp) regular expression to match a string of N bytes valued 0 or 1 in OR

Tags: regex, mfc

I have a string of, say for example, 6 bytes; each can be valued '0' or '1'. Which is the CAtlRegExp regular expression that matches any 0/1 combination of these bytes but not all 0s?

For example:

```
0001010 Match
0000001 Match
0000010 Match
1111111 Match

0000000 No match
```

I thought something like

```
^[01][01][01][01][01][01]$
```

but this one matches also "000000"

And in POSIX regular expression?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you imply in the question, no other input is possible than a string mixed of zeroes and ones, all you have to is to find a one, or a non zero character, i.e. `1` or `[^0]`. This will give you a match if a one is found.

If your regex flavor supports look ahead, and you want syntax checking in the regex as well, you could try

```
(?=[01]{6})0*1
```

This does a positive look ahead to ensure 6 (change to length wanted) zeroes or ones, and then checks that a one, possibly prefixed by any number of zeroes, follows.

EDIT: Checked out CAtlRegExp and it doesn't support look ahead :(. But I've got an even simpler regex that probably does the job:

```
{0*1+[01]*}
```

This doesn't verify the length, but it should satisfy your other needs. Also captures the string, if that's what you want (CAtlRegExp flavor). If not, remove the braces.
Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: The "look ahead" one doesn't works exactly as expected... however the second one does what i need, thanks :). Just as a curiosity exercise... do you figure out how i can match exactly 6 bytes with CAtlRegExp?

Comment: @Picci - Of the top of my head, the simplest solution would be to have 6 alternatives. It gets quite messy, especially since CAtlRegExp doesn't support repetition (i.e. you'll have to repeat patterns). Try `{1[01][01][01][01][01]|[01]1[01][01][01][01]|[01][01]1[01][01][01]|[01][01][01]1[01][01]|[01][01][01][01]1[01]|[01][01][01][01][01]1}`. It tests 6 alternatives with a one in each position, allowing all other characters to be a zero OR a one.